# Android-like Smartphone Platform that Uses Python

Tags: android, mobile

I came from solid C++ background, then hop to Java EE (JSF development), .NET and now I am developing in Django + Python for web and Ubuntu app and recently I tried playing around with Android SDK.

I have to say out of those languages, Python is the most productive one for me.  And that makes me wonder..is there any mobile platform that uses Python exclusively as much as Android using Java?

I know that iOS uses Objective-C and well...Windows Phone uses .NET..

(This is NOT a language versus discussion).

Comment: Try Android NDK since you have solid C++ background. Check this http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/mo-python-sl4a-1/index.html it might help you

Comment: will it be less overhead than the Java-like one?

Comment: I am from Java Background, So i find developing apps using Java much easier. Since you are from C++ and Python background you may find developing apps from C++ more easier.

Comment: @iNan yeah, you are right. Python + C++ is a good combination but apparently there is no mobile platform that adopt Python as the main development language. I just wish that some alternative to android exists (open-source, use Python and mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Symbian uses Python and Java ME, but no smartphone uses Symbian.

Though as iNan said, you can use python and/or C++ on Android.

Answer (score 0):

If Jython satisfies you, I heard this may be usefull: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/